# Configured KQL not working properly - CiscoISE event 60095 and 60098

Tags: logging, microsoft, cisco

I have a default KQL below which is used to detect when Cisco ISE failed backup, it fires an alert in Sentinel.
But it is not working as expected - it does fire an alert, but returning a timestamp only.

Nonetheless, I can see it is also supposed to return the hostname and IP of the device that actually triggered the '60095', '60098' events (failed backup).

**CiscoISEEvent | where TimeGenerated > ago(lbtime) | where EventId in ('60095', '60098') | project TimeGenerated, DvcHostname, DvcIpAddr | extend HostCustomEntity = DvcHostname | extend IPCustomEntity = DvcIpAddr**

I have further escalated this to our outsourced SOC where their engineers had a look and they had advised: *We suspect that it has something to do with the Event ID that's been captured in the raw logs which are not giving enough information and I believe we don't have visibility on this. We suggest filing a ticket to Microsoft for further troubleshooting on the mentioned Event IDs.*

I have raised this with MS and no reply yet.

I have tried some other KQL configs but none of them worked out in this regard.

**I guess my question at this point** **would be is it still a KQL issue, or is it more of the actual log issue?** (Coz those Cisco devices are managed by our MSPs, and we dont have visibility into them either)

Much appreciated for any directions so that I could dig further, as I am still a bit green on Sentinel.

Thanks in advance!

Below are from Cisco websites which elaborates their definition of the eventsIDs:
Message Code: 60095

Severity: ERROR

Message Text: ISE Backup has failed

Message Description: ISE Backup has failed

Local Target Message Format:  <seq_num> 60095 ERROR System-Management: ISE Backup has failed,

Remote Target Message Format: <pri_num>  <IP address/hostname> <CISE_logging category> <msg_id>   <seq_num> 60095 ERROR System-Management: ISE Backup has failed,

Message Code: 60098

Severity: ERROR

Message Text: ISE Log Backup has failed

Message Description: ISE Log Backup has failed

Local Target Message Format:  <seq_num> 60098 ERROR System-Management: ISE Log Backup has failed,

Remote Target Message Format: <pri_num>  <IP address/hostname> <CISE_logging category> <msg_id>   <seq_num> 60098 ERROR System-Management: ISE Log Backup has failed,